# How to measure RSSI of bluetooth devices on PC

Tags: signal, bluetooth

I'm a student in highschool doing research for a science project. I want to measure the RSSI of bluetooth devices on my Windows PC. I've searched on the internet for around 3 days but found no success.

The only method seems to be using a software called Bennett. However, it doesn't give me the signal strength. I contacted the company and they said Windows doesn't support such measurements. They told me to install Bluesoleil to run their software. However, Blueleil seemed to be not working on Windows10 and their website seemed quite sketchy.

I also heard that I could measure bluetooth signal strength on Mac OS. However, when I tried the same thing shown on online tutorial with my friend's mac, it didn't work. It seems like Apple removed the feature as time passed.

So I've thought about getting an Arduino and a HC-05 sensor and use some methods discussed on this website to get RSSI. But it would take some time to order the parts and get that thing working. I'm in a hurry as the deadline for my project is incoming, and I've got basically nothing done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Signal Strength" != RSSI.

RSSI is an *indicator* for how well *receivable* a receiver considers a signal – that's typically not inherently dominated by the signal strength, but by factors like noise and interference.

Thus, it's a *device-specific estimate* for how well the bluetooth device is able to receive someone else. Nothing more, nothing less. Be careful in your report not to completely conflate it with signal strength. If everything else stays constant (mainly: the other things using the 2.4 GHz band), then, however, RSSI will at least for the most part be *proportional* with some unknowable factor to received signal strength.

Bluetooth interface devices communicate with the host computer through a protocol called *HCI*. That's pretty standard, and it even offers a command to read the RSSI **of a logical bluetooth connection**.

I'm thus very surprised it should be hard under Windows or OS X to get an RSSI estimate using "on-board tools"; but then again, I'm an engineer and never use Windows for anything technical...

Under Linux, it'd be trivial to get the RSSI after connecting to a pairing partner device:

```
hcitool rssi AA:BB:CC:DD:EE..
```

where you of course replace the AA:.. string with the bt address of your connection.

`hcitool` is super handy. Quite possibly `hcitool scan` already contains all you want; `hcitool lescan` if you want to work with Bluetooth Low Energy beacons; `hcidump --raw` will simply print out all the packets flying by after triggering a scan, including info about RSSI.

(You can get a live [USB Linux image](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) that you don't have to install to anything; you'd just write it to a USB stick and boot your PC/laptop from it, and then would have a working Linux system without touching your main system.)