# How to continuously measure the RSSI of a Bluetooth signal on multiple PCs/devices?

Tags: bluetooth

Like WiFi, where one can scan and log the RSSI of a transmitted signal from a WiFi device on ***multiple*** PCs, do you know a way where one can log the RSSI of a Bluetooth signal on ***multiple devices/PCs/machines simultaneously***?

The answer in [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445800/how-to-measure-rssi-of-bluetooth-devices-on-pc?newreg=4b68ef58c08e426ea752b94d8f6fda35) only suggests a method to print the instantaneous RSSI value for a Bluetooth signal on a single device when both the devices (i.e., the one transmitting the signal and the other measuring that signal) are paired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple Linux machines to log the RSSI value of a BLE device. This can be done via BlueZ and the `btmon` command. Please see my answer here (specifically the **Bluetooth Low Energy** section) to see how this is done:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417017/bluetooth-le-signal-strength-linux/24417605#24417605